# Remove Characters with awk

Tags: awk, sed, ksh

I have a script that I'm working on to block IP address of failed login's on an SFTP server. I'm also using Centrify to hook the server into AD, and I've notice that Centrify logs users access differently than normal. I'm able to pull up the IP address of failed logins with the following one liner:

```
(grep sshd /var/log/messages | grep "AUTH_FAIL_PASSWD" | awk '{print $18}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ if ( $1 > 10) print $2 }')
```

With Centrify this gives the output of:

```
client=0.0.0.0
```

What I need to do remove "client=" so that I can pass just the IP address to the rest of the script.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Anytime you are piping like this with grep and awk you have made a mistake. awk can do that filtering for you. `/sshd/ && /AUTH_FAIL_PASSWD/ {print $18}`

Comment: You can do the de-duplicating in awk also (at cost of keeping the entries in memory) and without needing to sort.

Comment: `{if ($1 > 10) print $2}` can be rewritten as `$1 > 10 {print $2}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start be getting rid of all the useless pipes in your command line. Change the whole thing to just this one awk command:

```
awk '/sshd/&&/AUTH_FAIL_PASSWD/{cnt[$18]++} END{for (ip in cnt) if (cnt[ip] > 10) print ip}' /var/log/messages
```

Now - update your question to include some sample input (contents of /var/log/messages) and expected output and tell us in terms of the text in those files what it is you're trying to do.

Oh, I think I get it. This might be what you want:

```
awk '/sshd/&&/AUTH_FAIL_PASSWD/{sub(/.*=/,"",$18); cnt[$18]++} END{for (ip in cnt) if (cnt[ip] > 10) print ip}' /var/log/messages
```

Comment: Thank you! The second awk command does the trick. The overall goal of the script is to block the IP address of failed login attempts of an SFTP server. I've noticed my server getting hammered by the same group of IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can just dump this back to awk:

(grep sshd /var/log/messages | grep "AUTH_FAIL_PASSWD" | awk '{print $18}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ if ( $1 > 10) print $2 }' | awk -F"=" '{ print $2 }')

This last awk splits the string by an equals sign as the delimiter and prints the second element.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell, but if the ip is `$18`

```
... | awk '{if(split($18,a,/=/)==2) print a[2]; else print a[1] }' | ...
```

should do what you want

Even simpler

```
... | awk '{sub(/.*=/,"",$18); print $18}'  | ...
```

Further, I like pipes, in many cases they show clearly your intentions, but maybe it is worth accepting at least part of what other answers suggested

```
 awk '/sshd/&&/AUTH_FAIL_PASSWD/ {
      sub(/.*-/,"",$18; print $18}' /var/log/messages | sort | ...
```

Comment: Yes sorry, in /var/log/messages, Centrify dumps the IP in the $18 spot. But it dumps it as "client=0.0.0.0". Thank you.